# Javax XmlTransient not working for a enum field

Tags: java, xml

I have the following Enum class

```
public enum Test
{
 A,
 B,
 C
}
```

and the xml generated for this is

```
<xs:simpleType name="Test">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="A"/>
<xs:enumeration value="B"/>
<xs:enumeration value="C"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I don't want to include the C value in xml as I am using this for some internal logic only

Basically, I want the following generated xml

```
<xs:simpleType name="Test">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="A"/>
<xs:enumeration value="B"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I tried the below code but it's not working

```
public enum Test
{
 A,
 B,
 @XmlTransient
 C
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to write the custom marshal and unmarshal logic to achieve the result

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;


    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
    public enum Test
    {
     A,
     B,
     C
    }

    public class TestAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Test, Test>
    {
        public Test unmarshal(Test v) throws Exception
        {
            if (v == Test.C)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return v;
        }
    
        public Test marshal(Test v) throws Exception
        {
            if (v == Test.C)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```